# Spring boot property autowiring not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot `2.3.3.RELEASE` project.

Main Application class,

```
    @SpringBootApplication()
    public class TestApplication {
           ...
    }
    
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
    public class TestProperties {
      ...
    }
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({TestProperties.class})
    public class TestConfiguration {
    
    }

@Service
public class AmazonEmailService {

    private final AmazonSimpleEmailService client;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestProperties props;

    public AmazonEmailService() {
      props.getEmail(); // Here props is null ...
    }

}
```

Here, `TestProperties` autowiring is **null** in `AmazonEmailService`. Not sure what is missing.

Other Autowiring works in other classes.

Comment: is `TestProperties` is a `@Component`?

Comment: Does it require to be annotated with @Component

Comment: I am not sure of that. Alternatively you can try injecting `TestProperties` in the `constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use `@Autowired` on the constructor instead?

```
private TestProperies props;    

@Autowired
public AmazonEmailService(TestProperties props){
   this.props=props; 
   props.getEmail(); //Ok now.
}
```

This is because using `@Autowired` on property, Spring inject the value **AFTER** object create. But in your case, you try to use the props inside the contructor. At that moment, it's still null

Answer (score 0):

Add @Component annotation on TestProperties class

Comment: Property holder classes should not have an `@Component` annotation, instead use  `@ConfigurationProperties(...)`.